# $(e^{i})^n==e^{i n} $, Isn't this a natural thing?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
 Exp[I]^n == Exp[I n]
 Exp[I]^n == Exp[I n] // PowerExpand
```

what's missing? In order to get

```
 True
```

we have to use command

```
PowerExpand
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: You shouldn't use `PowerExpand` unless the variables are known to be real (and this assumption will be enforced throughout the code).  Use `Simplify`. -- I take it you're asking why there isn't an automatic simplification rule like there is for `1 + 1`. I'm afraid I don't know, but as *M* is a symbolic expression manipulator, one expects some limits on what is done automatically. Note that the simplification seems to be done automatically if you give `n` a numeric value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plain `Simplify` will do:

```
Exp[I]^n == Exp[I n] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

This is not a trivial simplification because in general $x^{ab} \neq (x^a)^b$.  Mathematica doesn't automatically perform nontrivial simplifications.  You must invoke [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) explicitly.

---

Be careful because `PowerExpand[expr]` doesn't return results that are valid in general.  `PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions -> True]` does. See the documentation for more details: [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html).

Comment: yes, I understand.

Comment: ((-1)^2)^(1/4)!=(-1)^(1/2) namely, 1!= i. Similarly                                (-1*-1)^(1/2)!=(-1)^(1/2)*(-1)^(1/2), namely 1!=-1